# creating nested dictionaries and lists from parsed CSV

Tags: python, pandas, list, csv, dictionary

I have been working on a project that involves parsing a CSV file in order to turn all the data into a very specifically formatted JSON following a complex schema. I have to custom make this program as the required complexity of the JSON makes existing converters fail. I am mostly there, I have run into one final roadblock though:

I have nested dictionaries, and occasionally there must be a list within those, this list will contain further dictionaries. This is fine, I have been able to complete that, BUT now I need to find a way to add more nested dictionaries within those. Below is a simplified breakdown of the concept.

the CSV will look something like this, where the @ before a tag indicates it's a list

```
x.a, x.b.z, x.b.y, x.@c.z.nest1, x.@c.z.nest2, x.@c.yy, x.d, x.e.z, x.e.y
ab, cd, ef, gh, ij, kl, mn, op, qr
```

this should result in the following JSON

```
 {
            "x": {
                "a": "ab",
                "b": {
                    "z": "cd",
                    "y": "ef"
                },
                "c": [
                    {
                        "z": {
                            "nest1": "gh",
                            "nest2": "ij"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "yy": "kl"
                    }
                ],
                "d": "mn",
                "e": {
                    "z": "op",
                    "y": "qr"
                }
            }
        }
```

This is one issue that I haven't been able to solve, my current code can only do one dictionary after the list item, not further. I also need to be able to somehow do the following within a list of dictionaries:

```
"c": [
                    {
                        "z": {
                            "nest1": "gh"
                        },
                        "zz": {
                            "nest2": "ij"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "yy": "kl"
                    }
```

i.e. somehow add multiple nested dictionaries within the dictionary in the list. The problem with this occurs within the fact that these aren't reference-able by name, so I do not know how I could potentially indicate to do that within the CSV format.

Here is the code I have that works up to the first dictionary nested within a list:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from os.path import exists

# df1 = pd.read_csv("excelTestFacilities.csv", header = 1, sep=",", keep_default_na=False, engine="python")
# df2 = pd.read_csv("excelTestFacilityContacts.csv", header = 1, sep=",", keep_default_na=False, engine="python")
# df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how = 'inner')

df = pd.read_csv("csvTestFile.csv", header = 1, sep=", ", keep_default_na=False, engine="python")


#print(df) # uncomment to see the transformation

json_data = df.to_dict(orient="records")
#print(json_data)


def unflatten_dic(dic):
    """
    Unflattens a CSV list into a set of nested dictionaries
    """
    ini = {}
    for k,v in list(dic.items()):
        node = ini
        list_bool = False
        *parents, key = k.split('.')
        for parent in parents:
            if parent[0] == '@':
                list_bool = True
        if list_bool:
            for parent in parents:
                if parent[0] == '@':
                    node[parent[1:]] = node = node.get(parent[1:], [])
                else: 
                    node[parent] = node = node.get(parent, {})
            node.append({key : v})
        else:
            for parent in parents:
                node[parent] = node = node.get(parent, {})
            node[key] = v
    return ini


def merge_lists(dic):
    """
    Removes duplicates within sets
    """
    for k,v in list(dic.items()):
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            keys = list(v.keys())
            vals = list(v.values())
            if all(isinstance(l, list) and len(l)==len(vals[0]) for l in vals):
                dic[k] = []
                val_tuple = set(zip(*vals)) # removing duplicates with set()
                for t in val_tuple:
                    dic[k].append({subkey: t[i] for i, subkey in enumerate(keys)})
            else:
                merge_lists(v)
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            dic[k] = list(set(v))   # removing list duplicates

def clean_blanks(value):
    """
    Recursively remove all None values from dictionaries and lists, and returns
    the result as a new dictionary or list.
    """
    if isinstance(value, list):
        return [clean_blanks(x) for x in value if x != ""]
    elif isinstance(value, dict):
        return {
            key: clean_blanks(val)
            for key, val in value.items()
            if val != "" and val != {}
        }
    else:
        return value

def add_to_dict(section_added_to, section_to_add, value, reportNum):
    """
    Adds a value to a given spot within a dictionary set.
    section_added_to is optional for adding the set to a deeper section such as facility
    section_to_add is the name that the new dictionary entry will have
    value is the item to be added
    reportNum is the number indicating which report to add to, starting at 0
    """
    if section_added_to != '':
        end_list[reportNum][section_added_to][section_to_add] = value
    else:
        end_list[reportNum][section_to_add] = value

def read_add_vals(filename_prefix, added_to, section):
    for i in range(len(end_list)):
        temp_list = []
        filename = filename_prefix + str(i+1) + ".csv"
        if not exists(filename):
            continue;
        temp_df = pd.read_csv(filename, header = 1, sep=",", keep_default_na=False, engine="python")
        temp_json = temp_df.to_dict(orient="records")
        for y in temp_json:
            return_ini = unflatten_dic(y)
            temp_list.append(return_ini)
        add_to_dict(added_to, section, temp_list, i)
                    
global end_list
end_list = []
for x in json_data:
    return_ini = unflatten_dic(x)
    end_list.append(return_ini)

#read_add_vals('excelTestPermitsFac', 'facility', 'permits');


json_data = clean_blanks(end_list)

final_json = {"year":2021, "version":"2022-02-14", "reports":json_data}
print(json.dumps(final_json, indent=4))
```

There is some parts of this code that are involved in other components of the overall end JSON, but I am mainly concerned with how to change unflatten_dic()
Here is my current working code for changing unflatten_dic(), even though it doesn't work...

```
def list_get(list, list_item):
    i = 0
    for dict in list:
        if list_item in dict:
            return dict.get(list_item, {})
        i += 1
    return {}    
            
def check_in_list(list, list_item):
    i = 0
    for dict in list:
        if list_item in dict:
            return i
        i += 1
    return -1  

def unflatten_dic(dic):
    """
    Unflattens a CSV list into a set of nested dictionaries
    """
    ini = {}
    for k,v in list(dic.items()):
        node = ini
        list_bool = False
        *parents, key = k.split('.')
        for parent in parents:
            if parent[0] == '@':
                list_bool = True
        previous_node_list = False
        if list_bool:
            for parent in parents:
                print(parent)
                if parent[0] == '@':
                    node[parent[1:]] = node = node.get(parent[1:], [])
                    ends_with_dict = False
                    previous_node_list = True
                else:
                    print("else")
                    if previous_node_list:
                        print("prev list")
                        i = check_in_list(node, parent)
                        if i >= 0:
                            node[i] = node = list_get(node, parent)
                        else:
                            node.append({parent : {}})
                        previous_node_list = False
                        ends_with_dict = True
                    else:
                        print("not prev list")
                        node[parent] = node = node.get(parent, {})
                        previous_node_list = False
            if ends_with_dict:
                node[key] = v
            else:
                node.append({key : v})
        else:
            for parent in parents:
                node[parent] = node = node.get(parent, {})
            node[key] = v
        #print(node)
    return ini
```

Any, even small, amount of help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working in what seems to be all scenarios. Here is the code that I made for the unflatten_dic() function.

```
def unflatten_dic(dic):
    """
    Unflattens a CSV list into a set of nested dictionaries
    """
    ini = {}
    for k,v in list(dic.items()):
        node = ini
        list_bool = False
        *parents, key = k.split('.')
        # print("parents")
        # print(parents)
        for parent in parents:
            if parent[0] == '@':
                list_bool = True
        if list_bool:
            for parent in parents:
                if parent[0] == '@':
                    node[parent[1:]] = node = node.get(parent[1:], [])
                elif parent.isnumeric():
                    # print("numeric parent")
                    # print("length of node")
                    # print(len(node))
                    if len(node) > int(parent):
                        # print("node length good")
                        node = node[int(parent)]
                    else:
                        node.append({})
                        node = node[int(parent)]
                else: 
                    node[parent] = node = node.get(parent, {})
            try:
                node.append({key : v})
            except AttributeError:
                node[key] = v 
        else:
            for parent in parents:
                node[parent] = node = node.get(parent, {})
            node[key] = v
    return ini
```

I haven't run into an issue thus far, this is based on the following rules for the CSV:

@ before any name results in that item being a list

if the section immediately after a list in the CSV is a number, that will create multiple dictionaries within the list. Here is an example

```
x.a, x.b.z, x.b.y, x.@c.0.zz, x.@c.1.zz, x.@c.2.zz, x.d, x.e.z, x.e.y, x.@c.1.yy.l, x.@c.1.yy.@m.q, x.@c.1.yy.@m.r
ab, cd, ef, gh, , kl, mn, op, qr, st, uv, wx
12, 34, 56, 78, 90, 09, , 65, 43, 21, , 92
```

This will result in the following JSON after formatting

```
"reports": [
        {
            "x": {
                "a": "ab",
                "b": {
                    "z": "cd",
                    "y": "ef"
                },
                "c": [
                    {
                        "zz": "gh"
                    },
                    {
                        "yy": {
                            "l": "st",
                            "m": [
                                {
                                    "q": "uv"
                                },
                                {
                                    "r": "wx"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "zz": "kl"
                    }
                ],
                "d": "mn",
                "e": {
                    "z": "op",
                    "y": "qr"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "x": {
                "a": "12",
                "b": {
                    "z": "34",
                    "y": "56"
                },
                "c": [
                    {
                        "zz": "78"
                    },
                    {
                        "zz": "90",
                        "yy": {
                            "l": "21",
                            "m": [
                                {
                                    "r": "92"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "zz": "09"
                    }
                ],
                "e": {
                    "z": "65",
                    "y": "43"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

It is easiest to use recursion and `collections.defaultdict` to group child entries on their parents (each entry is separated by the `.` in the csv data):

```
from collections import defaultdict
def to_dict(vals, is_list = 0):
  def form_child(a, b):
    return b[0][0] if len(b[0]) == 1 else to_dict(b, a[0] == '@')
  d = defaultdict(list)
  for a, *b in vals:
     d[a].append(b)
  if not is_list:
     return {a[a[0] == '@':]:form_child(a, b) for a, b in d.items()} 
  return [{a[a[0] == '@':]:form_child(a, b)} for a, b in d.items()]
```

---

```
import csv, json
with open('filename.csv') as f:
  data = list(csv.reader(f))
  r = [a.split('.')+[b] for i in range(0, len(data), 2) for a, b in zip(data[i], data[i+1])]
  print(json.dumps(to_dict(r), indent=4))
```

Output:

```json
{
    "x": {
        "a": "ab",
        "b": {
            "z": "cd",
            "y": "ef"
        },
        "c": [
            {
                "z": {
                    "nest1": "gh",
                    "nest2": "ij"
                }
            },
            {
                "yy": "kl"
            }
        ],
        "d": "mn",
        "e": {
            "z": "op",
            "y": "qr"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this definitely seems to work for the problem, thanks for the effort :) I happened to just solve the issue on my own about 15 minutes ago, I have also posted my solution. It's not the cleanest but it accounts for almost every scenario I have thought of